# How do to access Meteor settings file

Tags: meteor

Is there a way to access my settings file within the `client/main.html` file. Within the app I can use use `{Meteor.settings.public.appName}`but that doesn't work within this file and I'm not sure why.

Path: `client/main.html`

```
<head>
  <title>{Meteor.settings.public.appName}</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="react-target"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote is not valid html, and you are not inside a Blaze template either. So that won't work, right.

You can access these objects in blaze templates, e.g.:

```html
<template name="mytemplate">
  {{Meteor.settings.public.appName}}
</template>
```

but the `head` of your page cannot be a template. Also, it seems like you were planning on using React rather than Blaze, so then you need to write a React component. But within that you can access your settings just as easily (just like any other variable in your scope), e.g.:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<div>
        My app is called: {Meteor.settings.public.appName}
      </div);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, so it's not possible to access objects within `head`?

Comment: There is no reactivity inside the head, the Blaze compiler does not at least take it into account. However you can dynamically change the head tags inside `Template.body.onRendered` or other `onRendered` functions using jQuery.

Comment: You can use the react helmet. Changing titles with helmet is common especially for SPAs crawling.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this was to use react helmet, as @Pual Paulincai, suggested.

https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet